# How to execute a published Ruby Gem CLI app

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a CLI Ruby Gem several months ago and have just gotten around to publishing it. How can I test out executing the gem to ensure it was set-up/published correctly? Typically, I run `bin/run` in the terminal from the gem's root directory but I'm not sure how to run it from a Rails directory with the gem installed, for example. Basically just want to make sure I did everything right and it's working as expected.

Here's the gem for reference: https://rubygems.org/gems/phl-covid-testing

Comment: Well if you add it to a Rails app and the gem supplies an executable, it should be accessible with `bundle exec my_gem <command>`. But, it looks like this is just a plain Ruby CLI (no rails required), so you can just do `gem install my_gem` on the system and test it that way as well. Or you can make a new Gemfile somewhere and install it through there.

Comment: @maxpleaner made the updates suggested by @esotericpig, then tried this and got a pretty gnarly error (although it seems like I'm getting closer): ```/Users/brianfirestone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib/phl-covid-testing (LoadError)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems with this. But first, let me address your original question.

To test it on the command line (terminal):

```
$ gem install phl-covid-testing
$ which run
$ run
```

To test it in your Bundler project, add `phl-covid-testing` to your Gemspec/Gemfile. Then do this:

```
$ bundle install
$ bundle exec run
```

Now for the problems. The first problem you can see above is that you named your script `run`. This will be put on the user's path. It'd be better to rename your `bin/run` script to `bin/phl-covid-testing` or something else.

Next, I don't know if you did `chmod +x` on your script file in `bin/`, but I'll assume you did. However looking at the contents of the file, you have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "bundler/setup"
require "./lib/environment"

PHLCovidTesting::CLI.new.call
```

You shouldn't use `./lib/environment`, instead just do `require 'environment'`. You also don't need `require "bundler/setup"`. If you're testing locally, just use `bundle exec bin/run`.

Next, don't use the name `environment.rb`. I suggest renaming this file to the name of your Gem, so it would be `phl-covid-testing.rb`.

Lastly, your [repo](https://github.com/bfirestone23/phl-covid-testing) has a lot of unnecessary files. Remove `.DS_Store` and `phl-covid-testing-0.1.0.gem` and also add these to `.gitignore`:

```
# .gitignore
.DS_Store
*.gem
```

There might be more files that you need to ignore or more problems, but these are the major ones that I see at a glance.

## EDIT:

I decided to add how you can test this without uploading to RubyGems.org.

If you're using `bundler` and `rake` and you have `require 'bundler/gem_tasks'` in your `Rakefile`, then you can do this:

```
$ bundle exec rake install:local
```

This will build and install the Gem locally.

Else, you can also do this using the `gem` command manually:

```
## Remove old gems (optional).
$ rm -v *.gem

$ gem build phl_covid_testing.gemspec
$ gem install *.gem
```

See the [official doc](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem) for more information.

Then try to run the script as I mentioned earlier:

```
$ phl_covid_testing
## Or with bundler:
$ bundle exec phl_covid_testing
```

Comment: thanks for the corrections! I appreciate it. I made those updates and am still having trouble running the gem (attempting to do so in terminal). Since I updated the executable file name, I assume these are the commands I should be running:

`$ gem install phl-covid-testing`
`$ which phl-covid-testing`
`$ phl-covid-testing `

Excluding the entire stack trace for brevity, the error is: ```/Users/brianfirestone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib/phl-covid-testing (LoadError)```

Comment: Oh ok, so inside of your `phl-covid-testing`, you want to change the require to `require 'phl-covid-testing'` without the `./lib/` part. You might be able to use require_relative instead, but I think better to just do it that way. `which` isn't necessary of course, but helpful to see where it's located. If you want to try it locally (without pushing to RubyGems), if you have `require 'bundler/gem_tasks'` in your `Rakefile`, then you can just do `bundle exec rake install:local` or you can do `rake install:local` or do it manually with `gem build *.gem && gem install *.gem`

Comment: I edited my answer to include local testing.

Comment: you're an absolute saint! this got me there and all is now well. thanks a ton.